# Javascript - How to download JSON/AJAX files and access it offline

Tags: javascript

As the title says. I have the following code below for javascript which fetch a file from webserver. My problem is that i want the user to access/load the JSON inside `<script>` tag and make it available for offline use? E.g if the user is does not internet the `<script>` would still fetch the files. Is there any way to achieve it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Convert a JavaScript object into a JSON string, and send it to the server.</h2>

<script>
var myObj = { name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York" };
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
window.location = "demo_json.php?x=" + myJSON;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ajax requires a connection to a server.

Comment: to do that you will need to save that ajax result in some sort of database or as some sort of file and also you will need to  implement logic in your code that when you are without the internet connection, code use that ajax information from database or from some file.

Comment: Store stuff in localstorage if it is not huge.

Comment: @DanielA.White i know. but it there any other way to retrieve the data from the server and save it offline?

Comment: @Nezir how can i achieve that? and how will i call the file once's it is saved?

Comment: @epascarello how will i do that? and where is this localstorage? is it the drive of the computer?

Comment: you can use Service Workers too, if IndexedDB or localStorage is not enough. Whenever you are offline, you can pass along whatever you stored last time. You can also combine Service Worker and IndexedDB to avoid unexpected cache expiration of any request.

Comment: If the JSON is small enough, make use of `localStorage`. If its big or if you are able to implement `serviceWorkers` make use of it to `cache` the response and `serve` it.

Comment: Look that is not task for beginner. You will need to learn step by step. 0- check are you connected on internet. 1- create ajax request and handle response. 2- save it to db or to file. 3- check are you on internet 4- create logic for reading file from db or file if you are not on internet. There are many steps to do that and you will need some time to get this work well.

Comment: @Nezir i see. im an average at Javascript coding. the reason im asking this is that i created an app similar to w33school tryit editor, but it is offline. and i want to know if its possible to fetch/retrieve AJAX/JSON requests to the server

Comment: as others have mentioned you would have to pre-fetch the data when online, cache it in the browser and then if when the user wants to use it they are offline at that time, then use the cached version. Next time you're online, check the server for updates. It's not a particularly simple task. It's a series of tasks, really. (Of course if the user is offline and never used your page before, then there's nothing you can do - you can't connect to a remote server if there's no network connection.)

Answer (score 1):

You can save the data into localStorage or indexDB, this will work fine if the user is using a newer browser.

Another thing you can do is create a service worker that will cache the data.

You can check out Google's documentation for service workers for offline apps here:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/offline/